# Shortcode inside a WordPress shortcode

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, shortcode

Using the ultimate shortcodes plugin (the lightbox shortcode) and some custom styling I create pop-up frequently across my site.  I as trying to simplify the use-case by including the shortcode and the custom styling within a custom shortcode.

So for example This is the code that I need to type to get the desired effect:

```
<p style="text-align: left;">[su_lightbox type="inline" src=".123"]Some Name<i class="fa fa-chevron-right float-right"></i>[/su_lightbox]</p>
<div class="123 mfp-hide">
This is the content
</div>
```

And This is my attempt at turning the above into a shortcode:

```
// Add Shortcode
function person_shortcode( $atts , $content = null ) {

    // Attributes
    extract( shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'name' => 'name',
            'numb' => 'numb',
        ), $atts )
    );

    // Code
return '<p style="text-align: left;">[su_lightbox type="inline" src=".'.$numb'"]'. $name .'<i class="fa fa-chevron-right float-right"></i>[/su_lightbox]</p>
        <div class="'. $numb .' mfp-hide">
        '. $content . '
        </div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'person', 'person_shortcode' );
```

So my question is how can I make the above work?

So far I have tried replacing the `su_lightbox` shortcode with its output from inside Firebug however this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could manually call [`do_shortcode`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) on the string your shortcode callback returns. Something like the following should work:

```
// Add Shortcode
function person_shortcode( $atts , $content = null ) {

    // Attributes
    extract( shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'name' => 'name',
            'numb' => 'numb',
        ), $atts )
    );

    // Code
return do_shortcode( '<p style="text-align: left;">[su_lightbox type="inline" src=".'.$numb.'"]'. $name .'<i class="fa fa-chevron-right float-right"></i>[/su_lightbox]</p>
        <div class="'. $numb .' mfp-hide">
        '. $content . '
        </div>' );
}
add_shortcode( 'person', 'person_shortcode' );
```

You also have a syntax error in this section of code:

```
src=".'.$numb'"]'
```

You probably intended this:

```
src=".'.$numb.'"]'
```

I've fixed this in the sample above.

Comment: Still doesnt seem to work the whole site goes blank after I add it ? Any advioce?

Comment: @LukaDadiani There was a syntax error in the code, I've fixed it.

Comment: thanks but it needs a dot before hand to indicate that its linking to a class? e.g [su_lightbox type="inline" src=".class_name"]Professor Lord Alec Broers [/su_lightbox]